# Mostrar "a.m. y p.m." en la hora actual Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy haciendo un reporte de datos, en el cual quiero mostrar la hora actual. En donde ya logré hacer eso, pero solo me muestra la hora, sin los símbolos de "a.m." y "p.m."

Tengo estos campos de hora en mi base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi controlador tengo esto:

**RegistrarController.php**

```
$hora = date("H:i:s");


$asistencia -> hora_ingreso = $hora;
```

Y en la vista , específicamente en la celda de la tabla donde muestro los datos, tengo esto...

**Registrar.blade.php**

```
<td>{{$asistencia->hora_ingreso}}</td>
```

**ACTUALIZO:**

De esta forma se muestran los datos de la hora actual en mi vista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el cual aplico el siguiente código para poder quitar esos dígitos de ceros que siguen después de los segundos.

```
<td>{{Str::limit($asistencia->hora_ingreso, 8, '')}}</td>
```

Adicional a la pregunta principal, existe otra forma de quitar esos ceros de la hora cuando se registren en el SQL Server y en la vista?

Gracias de de antemano.

Comment: Como te puso @Aprendiz en una respuesta, usa Carbon para tratar fechas y horas y en el formato usa la 'A' para mostrar el A.M. o P.M.

Comment: Duda ¿ya probaste formatear la salida de tus datos como te recomendé (aún para la edición que muestras)?

Answer (score 3):

Usa el método [`isoFormat()`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) que ya esta en Laravel gracias a la biblioteca **Carbon**.

De este modo te lo ejemplifico:

```
$horaFormateada = now()->isoFormat('H:mm:ss A');
```

Lo cual me otorgaría una salida como la siguiente:

> 20:01:38 PM

**EJEMPLO**

Tenemos una consulta de este modo:

```
$data = Producto::select('created_at')->get();
```

Enviamos esa **`data`** a la vista e iteramos de esta forma:

```
@foreach($data as $valor)
    {{ created_at->isoFormat('H:mm:ss A') }}
@endforeach
```

Lo cual te va a devolver en el navegador una salida como esta:

> 20:13:22 PM

Aclaración

> De modo que usas las herramientas que te provee el mismo framework y no mezclas PHP puro con la sintaxis de Laravel lo que en cierto modo *ensucia* el código.

Answer (score 0):

Modifica los parámetros de la función `date` para utilizar otro formato

```
date("H:i:s A");
```

Comment: Si realice lo que comentas, pero solo colocaba la "a" en minúscula, pero no funcionaba, o es que debo ponerlo en mayúscula la letra "a"?

Comment: Si, debe ir con mayúscula

Comment: Lo intenté pero me devuelve el mismo valor, como si no cambiara nada.

Answer (score 0):

Concuerdo con @Jonathan Orta al modificar la función `date` para logar obtener un AM o PM.

Pero si realmente te interesa obtener específicamente un `a.m` o un `p.m` puedes concatenar lo siguiente al resultado:

```
$indicador = ( date("H") < 12 ) ? "a.m" : "p.m";
$hora = date("H:i:s");
$asistencia -> hora_ingreso = $hora . " " . $indicador;
```

Lo anterior está validando y guardando en `$indicador` si la hora dada en formato 24 horas es menor a 12, si se cumple esta condición va a decir que es `a.m` si no, va a decir que es `p.m`

Saludos.

Actualización:

De acuerdo a lo que me comentabas, tienes en la variable `$hora` un tipo TIME que luce más o menos así:

```
12:40:10:PM
```

Entonces, yo lo que te recomendaría sería remover esas últimas dos letras de la hora, es algo sencillo:

```
$hora = "12:40:10:PM";
$nueva_hora = substr($hora, 0, 8);
```

Utiliza esto si tu valor de `$hora` es igual a 12:40:10PM sin los dos puntos que separan a la hora y al PM:

```
$nueva_hora = substr($hora, 0, 7);
```

Esto nos daría el valor final:

```
12:40:10
```

Lo que hicimos fue extraer desde la primera letra (índice 0) hasta la letra número 9 (índice 8) considerando que tu formato de hora siempre será `HH:MM:SS` (todo esto con ayuda de la función `substr`, encuentra más información [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php) sobre esta función)

Ahora, nos falta extraer la hora de nuestra variable `$nueva_hora`. Para eso, separaremos por el delimitador `:` para poder sacar la hora, esto es:

```
list($hora, $minutos, $segundos) = explode(":", $nueva_hora);
```

Con `list`, guardamos los valores exactos de lo que resulte en tres partes con nuestro `explode` hacia la variable `$nueva_hora`. Encuentra información sobre `list` [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.list.php) y `explode` [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.list.php)

Entonces, el código quedaría:

```
$hora = "12:40:10:PM";
$nueva_hora = substr($hora, 0, 8);
//aquí cambia de 0 a 7 por si no ocupabas el símbolo :
list($hora, $minutos, $segundos) = explode(":", $nueva_hora);
$indicador = ( $hora < 12 ) ? "a.m" : "p.m";
$asistencia -> hora_ingreso = $nueva_hora . " " . $indicador;
```

Comment: Esto no entrará en conflicto con el tipo de dato "TIME" en la base de datos?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que si entra en conflicto? Es que como dijiste que la fecha la tomabas de la actual me imagino que ya consideraste ocupar como cabecera de tu script la función `date_default_timezone_set` con el valor del país de donde eres, lee esto https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php e implementa como ejemplo esto en la cabecera de tu script, o sea, al principio: `date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");` si es que eres de México y tu script va a ser usado solo en este país

Comment: Claro, eso ya lo tengo hecho. Lo que me refería es que cuando agregaba la letra 'a', en date("H:i:s **a**"); me mostraba mensaje de error, porque el campo de la variable en la base de datos es tipo "TIME", y cuando insertaba, ésta se agregaba, por ejemplo. "12:40:10:PM" el "PM" no aceptaba que tenga el valor PM por que lo tomaba como String.

Comment: Ok, voy a actualizar mi respuesta

Comment: Solo como último, ¿tienes como valor "12:40:10:PM" o "12:40:10PM" sin los dos puntos ":" que separan a la hora del PM?

Comment: Ya te actualicé la respuesta, revísala

Comment: Realizando los pasos mencionados, me muestra el siguiente mensaje de error **Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.** Adicional a esto, actualizo el mensaje para ver como me muestran los datos en la vista, solo mostrando la fecha actual, sin mostrar "am" o "pm"

Comment: Hola, ¿y al final utilizaste el mismo ejemplo que te compartí para poder tomar el valor recuperado de tu db, separarlo e imprimir el string final o cómo le hiciste?